# How do I put links to external pages into a navigation bar menu section?

Tags: google-sites

My Google Sites page (using the new Google Sites, not classic) has several external links in the navigation bar, e.g. GitHub, LinkedIn, etc. How do I add these external links to a menu section in the navigation bar? I created a new menu bar section called "External Links," but I can't find a way to add links to it. I can only add new subpages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. New links cannot be created from the **kebab** button
   [image]
2. Use the **Add** button (+)
   [image]
3. Select **New Link**
   [image]
4. Enter the **link**, the **name**, and click **Done**
   [image]
5. If the menu has no child page to select (or selected), the link will be created outside the menu, at the same level as the currently selected page
   [image]
6. You can drag the link into the menu using the link icon
   [image]  
   [image]